TypeORM - one-to-one relationship is null
First time using TypeORM, so i'm sorry if it's a very basic issue.
I have two entities: user and params:
@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({ unique: true })
    email: string;

    @Column()
    first_name: string;

    @Column()
    last_name: string;

    @Column({ unique: true })
    username: string;

    @Column()
    dob: Date;

    @Column()
    password: string;

    @OneToOne(() => Params, (params) => params.user)
    @JoinColumn()
    params: Params;
}

@Entity()
export class Params {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    usernameUpdate: Date;

    @OneToOne(() => User, (user) => user.params)
    user: User;
}

And there is one-to-one relationship between them. But, when i try to fetch params via user, it's always null:
const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({
            where: [{ id }],
            relations: ['params']
        });

User {
  id: 2,
  ...
  params: null // here.
}

Since i'm using TypeORM@0.3.20, I have data source defined like this:
export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    username: '',
    password: '',
    database: '',
    synchronize: true,
    logging: false,
    entities: [User, Params],
    subscribers: []
});

Sync is true and i've included params in entities array, restarted server and everything. Do i have to do manual migrations or what seems to be an issue here?
